# Find column value where maximum value in other column r

Tags: r, max

How can I find the "Feature" with the corresponding maximum value in the "Similarity" column? I have tried all the tips from other questions but it doesn't work. Thank you!

```
structure(list(Feature = c("Similarity_CEO", "Similarity_CFO", 
"Similarity_COO", "Similarity_CPO", "Similarity_CTO", "Similarity_CMO_CGO", 
"Similarity_CCO_CSO"), Similarity = c(0.647709116583091, 0.57912317932745, 
0.610563782018354, 0.568011165196869, 0.532707661875697, 0.595690196204727, 
0.575445639485977)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: What about: `df$Feature[which.max(df$Similarity)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the relevant **row**:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Feature == Feature[which.max(Similarity)])
         Feature Similarity
1 Similarity_CEO  0.6477091
```

To isolate the relevant `Feature` value:

```
df %>%
  filter(Feature == Feature[which.max(Similarity)]) %>%
  pull(Feature)
[1] "Similarity_CEO"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `slice_max`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  slice_max(Similarity)
```

Output:

```
         Feature Similarity
1 Similarity_CEO  0.6477091
```